# Matlab; Structure field name with valuable ( = number)

Tags: matlab

I am trying to assign valuable, which is number and given by for loop, to the name of structure field. For example, I would like to do as following,

A.bx, where A is name of structure(= char), b is part of field name ( = char) and x is valuable given by for loop. A and b is fixed or predefined.

Any comment is appreciated !

Comment: Well why cant you just use an Array or Cell instead?

Answer (score 4):

`genvarname(str,list)` generates a valid variable name in `str` [a string] in which at each iteration value in `str` is different from the exclusion list

And   `fieldname(S)`  returns a list of all the names of the field already in the structure `S` (use it to create a exclusion list)

Here is a code for what you want:

```
A = struct ();
for i = 1:5
    A.(genvarname ('b', fieldnames (A))) = i;
end
```

Read about 
1. [`genvarname(str,list)`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/genvarname.html) 
2. [`fieldnames(S)`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/fieldnames.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for prompt response. This is exact what I need and your suggestion worked perfectly. Thanks again for your help

Comment: That doesn't change the fact, that naming variables this way is really bad practice. You should rather use a cell array or normal array - whatever is applicable. It is much better than having `b1` to `b1234`.

Comment: @sebastian Yes that's what I suggested him too.

Answer (score 1):

You can name you struct fields using simple `sprintf`

```
A = struct()
for ii = 1:10
    fn = sprintf('b%d', ii );
    A.(fn) = ii; % use the struct
end
```

I tend to agree with [sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992755/matlab-structure-field-name-with-valuable-number#comment29771564_19993190) that suggested using arrays or cells over this type of field naming. In addition to cells and arrays you might find [`containers.Map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html) to be very versatile and useful.